# Django: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. Form submition

Tags: python, django, csrf, csrf-token

I'm getting "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect." error while doing a POST request to a django api from my localhost machine.
Trying to submit some easy form. Have problem with csrf token: CSRF token missing or incorrect.
Here are View:

```
def loginview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST["username"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        user = authenticate(username = username, password = password)
        if user:
            login(request, user)
            return render(request, "menu/index.html")
    else:
        return render(request, "menu/login.html")
```

Here is the Template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="{% url 'login' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input name="username" type="text">
    <input name="password" type="password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here are Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.place_order, name = "confirm"),
    path("signup/", views.signup, name = "signup"),
    path("login/", views.loginview, name = "login"),
]
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: Try removing session cookie for your host and start from there...